# Why doesn't this data binding work?

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, binding

I have a ViewModel class that contains a list of points, and I am trying to bind it to a Polyline. The Polyline picks up the initial list of points, but does not notice when additional points are added even though I implement INotifyPropertyChanged. What's wrong?

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Add!</Button>
    <Polyline x:Name="_line" Points="{Binding Pts}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5"/>
</StackPanel>
```

C# side:

```
// code-behind
_line.DataContext = new ViewModel();
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // The problem is here: NOTHING HAPPENS ON-SCREEN!
    ((ViewModel)_line.DataContext).AddPoint();
}

// ViewModel class
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public PointCollection Pts { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Pts = new PointCollection();
        Pts.Add(new Point(1, 1));
        Pts.Add(new Point(11, 11));
    }

    public void AddPoint()
    {
        Pts.Add(new Point(25, 13));
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Pts"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Answer updated, found the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your PointCollections Property to a dependency property:

```
public PointCollection Pts
        {
            get { return (PointCollection)GetValue(PtsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PtsProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Pts.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PtsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Pts", typeof(PointCollection), typeof(ViewModel), new UIPropertyMetadata(new PointCollection()));
```

BTW Doing this, you won't need to fire the PropertyChanged event.

Oh sorry, and your object needs to inherit from DependencyObject

```
    public class ViewModel : DependencyObject 
{ 
//... 
}
```

Comment: It is usually not recommended to implement ViewModels as DependencyObjects, which are much heavier than POCO implementing INotifyPropertyChanged... anyway, it won't change anything in that case

Comment: Thanks, did you test your answer? Using INotifyPropertyChanged works for me when I use it for other properties, just not for the point collection.

Comment: Yeah  tested it, I changed the code when creating a point, instead of Pts.Add(new Point(25, 13)); I did Pts.Add(new Point(random.Next(0,100), random.Next(0,100))); and all the new random points were created and displayed on the screen.

Comment: Thanks. I heard one shouldn't use both INotifyPropertyChanged and dependency properties in the same object; so potentially, I'd have to reprogram the rest of the ViewModel to use DPs. However, I just did a simple test that suggests using INotifyPropertyChanged for some properties and DPs for others DOES work.

Answer (score 4):

It is quite likely that since it is binding to the collection, it will need something like `ObservableCollection<T>`. What happens if you switch from `PointCollection` to [`ObservableCollection<Point>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)?

Comment: I just tested the same scenario, the binding itself works (the Points property contains the new points)... but for some reason, the PolyLine isn't updated

Comment: ObservableCollection<Point> does not work. Even the initial line does not appear on the screen; apparently Polyline doesn't support binding to ObservableCollection<Point>, nor does it support List<Point>.

Answer (score 1):

i got it to work as a POCO by implementing INotifyCollectionChanged instead of INotifyPropertyChanged.